# downloading files on iOS automatically opens a new window

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, blob

I'm working on a script that downloads a file after entering the website, the only problem is that it needs a popup to appear "Do you want to download file x?" instead, after entering the website, it opens this file immediately in a new tab without asking. I'm pasting the code, maybe someone had a similar problem. The problem mainly occurs on iOS

```
export function downloadFile(
  url: string,
  options?: RequestInit,
  filename = 'file.txt',
): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);

      if (!response.ok) {
        reject(response);
        return;
      }

      const blob = await response.blob();
      const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = downloadUrl;

      const contentDisposition = response.headers.get('content-disposition');
      const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition?.match(/filename="?(.+)"?/i);

      if (fileNameMatch?.length === 2) {
        filename = fileNameMatch[1];
      }

      link.download = filename;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
      resolve();
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: *”it needs a popup to appear”* but you are not creating any popups instead you are simply downloading directly.

Comment: Why would I create something? The idea is to force iOS to show the download prompt that is built into Safari every time